# How can I invert my temperature to display in the positive domain?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, pde

[The experimental set up and analytical solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhOYh.jpg) I am trying to solve a parabolic PDE with the pdepe function in MATLAB. The code runs fine, but the temperature is in the inverted direction when I use my boundary conditions as it is in the physical situation.  I can interpret the results and it matches what I am looking for, but I want to be able to display the temperature in both the correct magnitude and direction. What am I missing?

I can swap the boundary surfaces, that is, swap x=0 and x=L, (while keeping the boundary conditions the same); and the temperature would be in the correct direction but the distance is now inverse.

```
L = 0.1524;    
k = 0.0022;    
cp = 1.92;    
rho = 0.946;   
tend = 18;     
Flux = 1.1;     

m = 0;
x = linspace(0,L,200);
t = linspace(0,tend,100);

sol = pdepe(m,@pdex1pde,@pdex1ic,@pdex1bc,x,t);
Temperature = sol(:,:,1);

surf(x,t,Temperature)
title('Surface Temperature')
xlabel('Distance x')
ylabel('Time t')
zlabel('Temperature (C)')

function [c,f,s] = pdex1pde(x,t,u,DuDx)
global rho cp k
c = rho*cp;
f = k*DuDx;
s = 0;

function [Temperature] = pdex1ic(x)
Temperature = 25; 

function [pl,ql,pr,qr] = pdex1bc(xl,ul,xr,ur,t)
global Flux k
pl = 0; 
ql = 1/k;
pr = Flux;
qr = 1;
```

The temperature is inverse. I expect a range up to 120, I'm getting a line that terminates at about -120.

[The result of the numerical solution that shows the inverted temperature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra3Ia.jpg)

Comment: I don't know what's wrong in your model, but just as a detail, the function `[Temperature] = pdex1ic(x)` could have a simpler signature like `Temperature=pdex1ic`. You do not need the `x` input variable since you are not using it inside the function.

Comment: You also need `end` after your functions unless they are all really nested within each other

Comment: right now you code block doesn't evaluate in 2018a. What MATLAB version do you use?

Comment: 2019a. Try replacing pdex1pde with pdefun